# How Do I make a Splash Screen for a DeskShell Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, appjs

I have been experimenting with different frameworks for an application that i have been working on. I have mainly used appjs and deskshell. I am now trying deskshell. Can anyone help me with a splash screen? I have no idea how to even start it. Here is what i have so far (very basic).

Default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Anon VPN Connection Software </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
  </head>
  <body lang="en" onLoad="">
    <p> Anon VPN Connection Software </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anon VPN.desk:

```
{
  "name": "Anon VPN Connection Software",
  "author": "Dustin Angeletti",
  "Descript": "Anon VPN, SSH+, and SSH Connection Software",
  "licence": "MIT",
  "version": "1.0",

  "frontend": "chromium-portable",
  "backend": "node",
  "main": "app.js",
  "defaultLocation": "Default.html",
  "htdocs": "contents",
  "width": "800",
  "height": "500",
  "exitOnAppWinClose": true
}
```

app.js:

```
var running = deskShell.startApp({

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the API and associated documents has shown that there is no support for a splash screen (in the traditional sense).

At the end of the day, your application is just html. I suspect that you may mean 'how do I show an app'. If so then you should look at the first example on the deskshell.org website. You need to install the SDK so you can run deskshells, but once installed it's easy to run them.

You could have an index.htm with the following in it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hellow World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then you just need the app.desk file:

```
{
    "name": "html_helloworld",
    "version": "0.1",
    "author": "unknown",
    "description": "Hello world example.",
    "licence": "MIT",
    "htdocs": "htdocs",
    "frontend": "chromium-portable",
    "backend": "none",
    "width": "300",
    "height": "300",
    "defaultLocation": "index.htm"
    ,"appSocket":false
}
```

Then all you need to do is setup the file structure as follows:

```
...\html_helloworld\app.desk
...\html_helloworld\htdocs\index.htm
```

then you should be able to launch it by double clicking on the app.desk file. I did the above and tested it, works fine.

I also tried your application (as you have posted) and it didn't work. The reason why is because I didn't create an app.js file in the same directory as the app.desk file. The next problem I had was that you have "backend":"node". I removed the "main" optoin from your app.desk file and changed "Backend":"node" to "backend":"none".

---

A quick update. Reread the original question and realised that there was an app.js provided. So I recreated the scenario that the original question provided. I used the following structure:

```
...\VPN.desk
...\app.js
...\contents\Default.html
```

Everything worked fine with no changes to the .desk file or the html. To test I double clicked the VPN.desk and it opened the application. No log file was generated. Note that I installed the windows SDK from http://deskshell.org/